# Raspberry PI autostart AppImage file

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I would like to start a program automatically on my Raspberry.
My application is an AppImage file. (Cloud Printing Program)

I tried adding the following line to the cron.

```
@reboot /home/pi/Desktop/BizPrint-armv7.AppImage -d -m rtorrent
```

But it does not work.

Can anyone help me, how to run an AppImage file automatically when the Raspberry Pi restarts?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Is there an error message? Does it run and crash? Is it reliant on some aspect of networking being up and running? Are there permissions problems? How did you try to debug it? What are the parameters? Do you need to change directory before running it? Does it need some specific environment variables?

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell I am quite a beginner and have no experience with Linux at all. I try to setup a raspberry pi in order to have a "server" that sends information to the printer in a restaurant. And this program must autostart in case the raspberry gets disconnected from power. 
First I tried this https://tutorials-raspberrypi.de/raspberry-pi-autostart-programm-skript/#:~:text=Immer%20wieder%20passiert%20es%2C%20dass,im%20Linux%20System%20zu%20hinterlegen. 
And created an autostart script - but when I start it I get this error:
"Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. "